# iOS - Start a function if app is closed

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder if it's possible with swift, start a function at a certain time, especially if the app is closed.

I tried a bit around but did not find anything useful.

I hope you can help me. 
Thanks

Comment: You can schedule local notifications and show like a remote notification to the user. Other than that, I think no. Your app can't run processes when it is not running, given how it leaves a lot of room for privacy breach and malicious activities. If it is running, you can schedule operations for a certain time using same local notifications.

Comment: That is shady shit, doing it after application is closed. You have an `applicationWillTerminate` method in your App delegate, that I think is the closest you come

Answer (score -1):

You can try to override functions like

```
applicationDidEnterBackground

applicationWillTerminate

applicationDidBecomeActive
```

Comment: You can't override this AppDelegate methods you need to add an observer at the view controller with a selector